# How to merge all the layers when export as 1 PNG file - NOT as individual each layer

Tags: layers, export, png, clipping-mask, mockup

Hi I have PSD file that i want to export the project as a PNG with the LAYERS like this

How to merge all layers when exporting as a single PNG file (1) but not each individual layer individually

[image]

[image]

Also, I have the PNG with the layers merged into a single file.
When I hover with the mouse, you can see the blue effect of the specific item on which the layers are placed

[image]
[image]

Comment: Simply put.. the PNG format does **not** support layers. It is not possible to do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to ask non-existent functionality. There's no such thing as multilayer PNG. If it must be a single PNG it can have only a single layer.  That single layer can have fully and partially transparent areas. But it cannot have a layer mask, smart object, alive adjustments, vectors, editable texts nor Photoshop's layer styles.

You must live with the mentioned limitations or save as PSD. Unfortunately only Photoshop opens that PSD without removing none of the effects which are vital for mockups. Some other programs have got recently abilities to understand various Photoshop's specialities, but for ex. GIMP is not one. It finds image layers, but knows nothing of adjustment layers nor smart objects.

I guess your blue rectangle around a photo in a PNG is transparent area, but that's a guess.

BTW. To merge several layers together in Photoshop you must select those layers simultaneously in the layers panel and right click to get option merge layers. The result can be unpredictable if you selected only a part of the layers, because merging removes blending modes and effects which can affect also to some unselected layers below.

Merging a complex layer composition which contains adjustment layers and blending modes should happen automatically right when one exports as PNG. If some layers must be omitted they can be simply closed in the layers panel. Vanished adjustment layers cannot be recovered from the merged PNG.